# Inpho Match-AT--orienting in LSR

Tags: inpho-match-at

My company receives GNSS in state plane / IMU in lat/long, but the control is in local. I need to be able to complete AT within Inpho and export to Summit. The Inpho support guy says that I have to convert my GNSS to local, but the Summit guy is certain that's not necessary, although his suggested technique bombs out.

Is there anyone out there who knows how to run the AT from local coordinates only?

Comment: You're getting state plane (meters or int'l feet or US feet) or latitude-longitude (degrees). By 'local', do you mean a local projected coordinate system? Could you also expand out some of the acronyms? IMU, AT (aerial triangulation? automated triangulation?)

Comment: yes, a local projected coordinate (what Inpho calls "Local space rectangular"). Each project has its own unique coordinate system. IMU is inertial measurement unit. GNSS is global navigation satellite system. AT is aerotriangulation.